# "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" on a fresh install of MySQL 5.6.15 on Windows after uninstalling an older version of MySQL

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

So, I've just installed MySQL 5.6.15 on my Windows machine, but for some reason I can't log in using "root" with no password.

```
C:\web\mysql-5.6.15-win32\bin>mysql.exe -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

However I can login with "ODBC" and no password:

```
C:\web\mysql-5.6.15-win32\bin>mysql.exe
Welcome blah blah blah
mysql> SELECT USER();
+----------------+
| USER()         |
+----------------+
| ODBC@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why can't I log in with "root" with no password?
I've tried uninstalling MySQL and installing it again, to no avail.

Comment: Usually, during installation, a password for the root user must be specified.

Comment: Ah, but to install MySQL, I unzipped the archive, and ran "mysqld.exe --install". I didn't use an installation wizard.

Comment: Then you cannot login as root.

Comment: Why? Is that something new in version 5.6? I remember installing older versions (e.g. 5.1) and the default was a "root" account without password.

Comment: Sorry that was just a guess. I never used windows version but it surprises me that the default root password is empty. In linux that never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found out what the problem was:

I uninstalled MySQL 5.1.70 by doing:

```
C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin>mysqld.exe --remove
```

It worked.

Then I installed MySQL 5.6.15 by doing

```
C:\web\mysql-5.6.15-win32\bin>mysqld.exe --install
```

It **appeared** to work. In fact what it did was re-installing the old version.

The solution is to rename or delete the old folder (C:\web\mysql-5.1.70) before running `mysqld.exe --install`

EDIT: Now I understand. `C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin` was in my Path...

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know why there isn't a "root" account without password by default, but here's how I solved the problem:

1. Stop the MySQL service (mysqld.exe)
2. Start the MySQL service with the following parameter: `--skip-grant-tables`
3. Log in to MySQL (mysql.exe) as root: `mysql.exe -u root` (it doesn't require a password, thanks to step 2)
4. Execute the following queries:
   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Exit MySQL
6. Stop the MySQL service
7. Start the MySQL service **without** the `--skip-grant-tables` parameter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same security issue when I had a fresh install of Mysql on windows after uninstalling the old version. I figured out a way that could possiblely resolve the problem:

After you have installed the new version of MySQL, go to MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin and launch **MySQLInstanceConfig.exe**. This will help you to reset your password and config will work well